# Capture videostream using C/C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, video-streaming, windows

I 'm working on a project which is client-server based. Client is a Windows application (Visual Studio 2012) and server is a C program running on Linux.

Server uses a webcam to capture and stream video (ffserver). Problem is I don't know how to program client to receive and play video (via a dialog box maybe). Do I have to make use of players like WMPlayer, VLC or not?

I 'm newbie and any help or recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your client supposed to do ? You writing some kind of video player? Probably you can start from here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13265148/2549281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side you could always use DirectShow to decode and render your stream.  Live555 can handle the stream and pass it to a graph.

[Render RTSP H.264 video stream using live555](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14710493/render-rtsp-h-264-video-stream-using-live555)

If you're unfamiliar with DirectShow and filters there's a lot of stuff on MSDN

[About DirectShow Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

That should allow you to render to a surface of your choosing, it's always wise to render something on no signal though, just so you can tell the difference between no stream and a blank stream.

Answer (score 0):

i think you will find both server and client side solution using simple vlc player on both end follow below link 
http://xmodulo.com/2013/09/live-stream-video-webcam-linux.html

Comment: I 've already tried similar thing with ffplay on client side. However, I don't want a pop-up window showing the stream, each time I run command `vlc http://<ip_address_of_webcam_host>:8080/stream.wmv` but an .exe (e.g. a dialog box that gets filled each time server streams video). Do you think this is possible? Thank's anyway.

Comment: if you are worried about running command each time on prompt you can create an .exe file and use system("vlc http://<ip_address_of_webcam_host>:8080/stream.wmv") in it, with this you will just have to click on the .exe file that will run vlc command for you

Comment: and one more thing it is possible windows has it's api and other function you can also use windows media player library which i guess are there in vs2012 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh828986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: check below link as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770870.aspx,  http://code4k.blogspot.in/2010/05/playing-mp3-in-c-using-plain-windows.html

Comment: [in reffering to system()]: You 're right about this, but pop-up window still remains. I 'm looking for an application where "video display window" shows up even if I have not video streaming (it will not display anything until a video stream arrives).

Comment: pop-up window you mean to say which one the .exe file we create or the vlc window???

Comment: I mean the player (in that case vlc window). I want the .exe to consists of a just a display window (either I have video streaming either not). I think that, what I 'm looking for is a Windows application (dialog-box) in Visual Studio.